# Modeling JSON message

Tags: c#, json, oop

I'm using a web service with this request format:

```
{  
   "type":"LogonReq",
   "id":"b43b301c-5216-4254-b3fc-cc863d4d6652",
   "date":"Wed, 16 Aug 2017 17:35:34 UTC",
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "userName":"user",
         "password":"password"
      }
   ]
}
```

Even though every message in the API requires only 1 set of parameters, the API still requires "parameters" to be an array.

Is it better practice to have the caller create the list or to create the list in the MessageBase constructor, or something altogether different ?
Which way would satisfy an OOP purist code reviewer?

```
public class MessageBase<T>
{
    public MessageBase() { this.parameters = new List<T>(); }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public List<T> parameters { get; set; }
}

public class LogonMessage{
       public string userName { get; set; }
       public string password { get; set; }
}

var logon = new MessageBase<LogonMessage>()
{
     date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss UTC"),
     id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
     type = "LogonReq",
 };

 logon.parameters.Add(new LogonMessage() { userName = "user", password = "password" });
```

or

```
public class MessageBase<T>
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public List<T> parameters { get; set; }
}

public class LogonMessage{
       public string userName { get; set; }
       public string password { get; set; }
}

var logon = new MessageBase<LogonMessage>()
{
    date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss UTC"),
    id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    type = "LogonReq",
    parameters = new List<LogonMessage>() { new LogonMessage() { userName = "user", password = "password" } }

};
```

Comment: What is the shortest path to functionality? The shorter way is generally the better.way, from several perspectives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably find many interesting opinions and answers to this. I can only give you mine based on my experience.

**I myself would probably initialize the list within the constructor**

However, since you are trying to get a good idea around the phylosophy of coding, here are some things to consider :

1) Does the MessageBase object **make sense** or is it **useful** with a NULL list? Is there any scenario where I want this list as null?

2) Actually, I would expect an OOP purist to say that you should not expose the "parameters" as a List. By exposing the object as a property, someone can do this:

```
login.parameters.Add()
```

Or this

```
logon.parameters = anotherListOfMine
```

In a way it does break encapsulation. You could make the list property read only (ie, with a protected/private setter) but "clients" of this class will still be able to access all properties and methods of the List and modify/handle them.

Now, you **have to** expose this in some way as you will be serializing/deserializing into JSON, so that poses a problem! Maybe you can have a private/protected List field and expose the values through a readonly property that exposes an IEnumerable and behind the scenes, you are doing:

```
get { return myPrivateList.ToArray(); }
```

3) But again, do you really win that much? Your next question should be "Who is my client?" If you are exposing this class to other developers, or is part of a framework, you might want to apply something like my point number 2, and limit the exposure. If this is internal to your application and your team maybe you should be pragmatic and simply expose the List as you are doing right now.

4) Alternatively, while still making it open, you could instead have a property of type IEnumerable so you can pass in any type.

5) Another option is to expose your list because you need to serialize it, but make it readonly. Have instead different methods, or non-serializable properties, of username and password. If these parameters are always the same that is. I am thinking this might not be your case.

I think I could go on and on this. I will stop here before you hit the downvote button :).